# Error in installing .sh file on Anaconda and Git Bash

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, anaconda, git-bash

download_hate_data.sh file consists of 3 folders of distinct memes images. But I don't know how to proceed further. It's asking for google image downloader and Chromedriver. I've installed both of them but still, it's showing the following error message.

**GitBash:**

Abrar@DESKTOP-3DSQVRQ MINGW64 ~/data (master)

```
$ ./download_hate_data.sh
For installation instructions visit https://github.com/hardikvasa/google-images-download
./download_hate_data.sh: line 5: googleimagesdownload: command not found
./download_hate_data.sh: line 6: googleimagesdownload: command not found
./download_hate_data.sh: line 7: googleimagesdownload: command not found
```

**Anaconda Prompt:**

````
(tensorflow) C:\Users\Abrar\data>bash download_hate_data.sh
For installation instructions visit https://github.com/hardikvasa/google-images-download

Item no.: 1 --> Item name = racist meme
Evaluating...
Looks like we cannot locate the path the 'chromedriver' (use the '--chromedriver' argument to specify the path to the executable.) or google chrome browser is not installed on your machine (exception: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable)

Item no.: 1 --> Item name = muslim meme
Evaluating...
Looks like we cannot locate the path the 'chromedriver' (use the '--chromedriver' argument to specify the path to the executable.) or google chrome browser is not installed on your machine (exception: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable)

Item no.: 1 --> Item name = jew meme
Evaluating...
Looks like we cannot locate the path the 'chromedriver' (use the '--chromedriver' argument to specify the path to the executable.) or google chrome browser is not installed on your machine (exception: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable)```
````

Comment: put `chromedriver` in folder with script which your run and maybe then script find it.

Comment: did you try `download_hate_data.sh --chromedriver /full/path/to/chromedriver` ?

Comment: _No I couldn't download this sh file still. I have tried your solution too._

Comment: did you download [chromedriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) for your system? Where do you put it ? You have to know full path with filename - on Windows it means with `chromedriver.exe` - and use it in `---chromedriver /full/path/to/chromedriver.exe` If you use wrong path then it can't find it and it can't use it. BTW: `chromedriver` means also you need web browese `Chrome`

Comment: Thanks guys it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Open Command Prompt and navigate to the folder where the script file is available.
Type Bash script-filename.sh and hit the enter key.
It will execute the script, and depending on the file, you should see an output.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).